# EWS WebCredentials User Type for running a console app

Tags: exchangewebservices

I wrote a console app that adds appointments to an end users calendar.

When I run the app under my own user id and password I can add appointments to the end user's calendar (I am a delegate on their calendar).

We created a "Service Account" to run this app under, that account shows up in outlook and has email. I am getting "401 Access Denied" under this "Service Account".

I looked online, but I cannot find out what are the Minimum Account Requirements (security settings) for a WebCredentials Accounts for EWS?

```
public static ExchangeService getExchangeService()
{
    ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);

    service.Url = new Uri(Config.OutlookServiceURL);
    service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(Config.OutlookUserID, Config.GetDelegatePassword());
    service.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    return service;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the service account should also have Full Access rights to that calendar, or it would need impersonation privileges for that MB.  Either would do, altho using impersonation would be some slightly different coding.

Comment: pjneary, I have it setup as a Delegate on the Calendar. I did notice though, after setting "manage calendar" in the drop down, under the delegate it did not save. Back to seeing what is the issue with that service account.

Answer (score 0):

In this case this "service account" was created and it was set to disabled. Enabling the account fixed the issue.